# Determine if point is in set of coordinates in java

Tags: java, gis

I have searched for an answer to this question, but I cannot seem to find a solution. What I need is I have a set of coordinates (of unknown length in the beginning) and I need to determine if a point resides inside of the polygon determined by this coordinate. However, I cannot use the `AWT` (as I originally thought I could), as the coordinates can range anywhere in the US.

I think I need to use a `for-loop`, with a series of `less than`, `greater than` checks. Am I on the right path, or is there an easier solution that I am not thinking of? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
49.006452278468664, 115.10363050431958
48.993314385809654, 115.04009921106841
49.03510754434096, 115.02009771650923
49.04825271759021, 115.08366905978859
```

Comment: *How* do the coordinates determine the polygon? Are we talking about a convex hull or are the coordinates in the same order as on the boundary of the polygon?

Comment: Please refer to the Convex Hull problem!

Comment: I am pulling the data from a KMZ file, and from what I can tell they are in order (although there are many points in the file, so I haven't checked them all).

Comment: Is the polygon known to be convex?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am getting data from http://www.spc.noaa.gov outlooks, so it really depends on what the forecasters draw.

Comment: Ok, so let me make sure I am on the right path. Basically I need to check if the point is to the right of every line segment on my polygon?

Comment: You have a random point to be the origin of a ray. If this ray intercepts the polygon a even number of times, the point is outside the polygon. If it intercepts a odd number of time, it is inside it.

Comment: Have you looked at the Getools/Vivid Solutions JTS library? It has built in methods for doing this (and about every other geometry type operation that you can think of), there is a PreparedBoundary.contains method that does what you need. I've got a project on Github that uses it if you want to have a look at what's involved in using it in real life: https://github.com/matthelliwell2/MinecraftOSLoader/tree/master/src/main/java/org/matthelliwell/minecraftosloader

Comment: I have not, but I am reluctant to add such a big library for this function, which I will essentially only need one method of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Haines wrote a great article on this: http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/

There are a few methods at your disposal, the Jordan Curve Theorem is fairly good but has some issues if your data creates a doughnut type polygon and your point is in the middle.

> Essentially, it says that a point is inside a polygon if, for any ray from this point, there is an odd number of crossings of the ray with the polygon's edges

You could also use the Angle Summation Test which is pretty slow but a surefire way to test if a point is inside a polygon.

> sum the signed angles formed at the point by each edge's endpoints. If the sum is near zero, the point is outside; if not, it's inside (Figure 2)

A third method is Triangle Test which will work well if your polygon is not too pointy (which I suspect it might be):

> The polygon is treated as a fan of triangles emanating from one vertex and the point is tested against each triangle by computing its barycentric coordinates.

If you can check that the shape is concave there are other methods at your disposal, I would recommend reading the article as it discusses many more ways to solve your problem than the ones listed here.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia [writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon):

> One simple way of finding whether the point is inside or outside a simple polygon is to test how many times a ray, starting from the point and going in any fixed direction, intersects the edges of the polygon. If the point is on the outside of the polygon the ray will intersect its edge an even number of times. If the point is on the inside of the polygon then it will intersect the edge an odd number of times. Unfortunately, this method won't work if the point is on the edge of the polygon.

For simplicity, it's probably easiest to cast the ray horizontally, so edges crossing the ray can be identified by the sign changing:

```
boolean inside(Point p, Point[] polygon) {
    int intersections = 0;
    Point prev = polygon[polygon.length - 1];
    for (Point next : polygon) {
        if ((prev.y <= p.y && p.y < next.y) || (prev.y >= p.y && p.y > next.y)) {
            double dy = next.y - prev.y;
            double dx = next.x - prev.x;
            double x = (p.y - prev.y) / dy * dx + prev.x;
            if (x > p.x) {
                intersections++;
            }
        }
        prev = next;
    }
    return intersections % 2 == 1;
}
```

Comment: So I would need to cast it both horizontally and vertically or would I just need to do one or the other?

Comment: All directions should give the same result.

Comment: Ok, I think I remember the math theory behind it now! Thanks! We only cast it in one direction, correct? (Like to the right only?)

Comment: In your code that you posted, when you have sgn, do you mean sin?

Comment: I tried this code, with the signum function, and unfortunately it does not seem to work for my case. It is not accurate in determining the point locations

Comment: Ah, I should probably update prev as I go around ... should work now. (I also fixed a corner case for vertices where p.y == poly[i].y)

Comment: Ok it looks like it should work! I'm having to troubleshoot another problem now! (KMZ coordinates and actual coordinates are not lining up).