# How to Check if Coordinates belongs to an geographical area in JAVA

Tags: java, geolocation, geographic-distance

I have coordinates , lets say coordinates point A `{ -73.93289103, 40.12354012}`. And i have a geographical area which consists of 4 coordinates

```
{-73.99863434, 40.7422142}
{-73.99131012, 40.73348236}
{-73.96737671, 40.76044846}
{-73.87309265, 40.77401733}
```

Now i want to check if my coordinate point A is inside this geographical area. And i want a generic formula for it. How could i start thinking a formula? In java

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675611/determine-if-point-is-in-set-of-coordinates-in-java

Comment: Yes, it works in general!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if point is in set of coordinates in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675611/determine-if-point-is-in-set-of-coordinates-in-java)